# Making an asynchronous call prior to a segue to the next view controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a bunch of view controllers (embedded navigation controller), and I need to make some async calls before I segue to the next screen. The problem is that I need to make this call at the time I click the button mapped to the segue, but since the async call hasn't returned yet, the segue is made and the next view controller is shown. How do people do this kind of thing to prevent view controller navigation happening before the async call is returned?

Comment: have you any code to show?

Comment: Don't, instead do it in the new controller

Comment: I can't do it in the next controller because the next view controller should only be displayed if the async method is successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can create an `@IBAction` for the `UIButton` and inside the function make the async call and launch the segue manually in the **completionHandler** using the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}`.

To create your segue manually just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Drag</kbd> from the `UIViewController` to the next one like in the following picture:

[image]

And then you will see to choose the type of segue like in this picture:

[image]

After you choose the `Show` type you can see the segue in the hierarchy of view in your left choose it to set the identifier for the segue like in this picture:

[image]
You can handle your problem launching the `segue` manually with the function `performSegueWithIdentifier`, you can reference in the web to find a lot of tutorials about how to create a the segue manually using Interface Builder.

Once you segue has been created you can call it in anywhere you want, in your case as you will calling it inside a **completionHandler** of an async call you need to put in in the main thread using the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}` function of Grand Central Dispatch.

Something like this code:

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    asyncFunction() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someID", sender: sender)
        }
    }
}
```

> **Edit**:
>   Note that in Swift 3 the syntax has changed:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    asyncFunction() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someID", sender: sender)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Well considering that I created the segue in IB by ctrl dragging from the button to the next view controller, how do I cancel the segue action that's kind of "behind the scenes"? Won't that still get executed?

Comment: What do you mean with cancel the segue?

Comment: Well if I just ctrl drag from button to view controller, the segue will happen when I click on the button. This doesn't happen in my code. It's a given when you make the connection (the action I selected is "Show").

Comment: Remove the segue from the button and make one between the two view controllers and give it an identifier

Comment: The way of make the segue manually it's not Ctrl+Drag from the `UIButton` to the next ViewController , it's just as @dan said you need to make the segue between the two `UIViewController` just Ctrl+Drag from the first to the second, from the `UIBUtton` what you need it's just an `@IBAction`

Comment: I see. I'm new to iOS development and didn't know you can do that. In fact, Apple's documentation doesn't make it too apparent that you can go from view controller to view controller. "To create a segue between view controllers in the same storyboard file, Control-click an appropriate element in the first view controller and drag to the target view controller. The starting point of a segue must be a view or object with a defined action, such as a control, bar button item, or gesture recognizer."

Comment: @u84six No problem, It's the way of create manual segues when you want, in any case inside the closure of my code you can handle to launch the segue if everything is good or not, it's up to you.

Comment: Can you give me the steps on how to make the connection? When I click the view controller icon at the top of the view controller in IB and ctrl drag, the only place it allows me to make the connection is an actual view. How do I make the connection to the view controller itself?

Comment: Victor's approach will work, just take care to display to the user that something is happening, or they'll keep tapping the button over and over

Answer (score -4):

It sounds like you're looking for it to run synchronously; so if you're using GCD call `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async` when putting the heavy lifting on the background thread, and when you need the segue to happen put things back onto the main thread by calling `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // handle error or segue }`

Comment: Will I be able to make this call and also show a wait timer?

Comment: you could show a wait timer before dispatching onto a background thread, and removing it once things are back on the main thread

Comment: @aduflo What you said it's not the recommend way to handle the problem, async call has made mainly to avoid the freeze of the UI.

Comment: @VictorSigler i assumed he wanted to freeze the UI based on this comment: `How do people do this kind of thing to prevent view controller navigation happening before the async call is returned?`